# Investigate the convergence of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Investigate the convergence of the series on the interval $x \in [0;1]$

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{1 + n^2x^2} $$

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1793315/show-that-sum-limits-n-1-infty-fracx1n2x2-is-not-uniformly-conver

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{1 + n^2x^2}=\frac{\pi}{2}(\coth \frac{\pi}{x}-\frac{x}{\pi})$$

Comment: Are you sure? The left-hand side is defined in $0$, while the right-hand side is not.

Comment: $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}\coth \frac{\pi}{x}=1$

Comment: @E.H.E: ...in which case for $x=0$ the left-hand side is $0$ and the right-hand side is $\frac \pi 2$. Maybe that equality is valid on $(0, 1]$, I don't know, but it surely is not valid on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Winther: Even interpreted as a limit, the equality is not true, see my comment above.

Comment: yes, as you said, the equality is true when $x\neq0$

Comment: @AlexM. Yes you are quite right. The series does not converge uniformly on any interval containing $x=0$ so the limit is not guaranteeds to equal the right hand side function value there. I should have read the question I linked to better. Thanks for correcting me.